# ffmpeg transcoding move to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, plex

I currently use windows free software called: AnyVideoConverter to convert my iPhone huge MOV files to MP4s that can be played on other devices via my plex server.
I want to automate that process so it runs in the background on one of my linux machines.
However I am struggling to get it working. Here is what I have so far.

```
Original file details:
Duration: 00:00:13.53
Original Video: 40MB
Video details: Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 3840x2160, 23453 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 600 tbc (default)
```

```
AnyVideoConverted file:
File Size: 5MB
Video Details: Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x2160, 2870 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
```

This format works great on all my devices

So far the closes I managed to get to that is this ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i original.mov -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -maxrate 3M -bufsize 3M -c:a aac -b:a 128k x264.mp4


File size:5MB
Video details:     Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 2160x3840, 3063 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
```

problem is that when I try to play it via plex I get:

Playback Error: This server is not powerful enough to convert video

What am I doing wrong here?

My knowledge of ffmpeg or video encoding/transcoding is zero. Can someone advise me how to get my mov files converted to mp4 so they can be played via plex without additional transcoding by plex and without reducing the resolution size of the converted video.

Any pointers ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Transcoding depends on the type of Plex client that is requesting the movie. You have two options here:

1. Set video streaming quality to maximum in all of your Plex clients. This way a transcoding is not necessary in most of the cases.
2. Disable video transcoding in your Plex server (there is an option for that in your server settings). If your server is not capable of transcoding a normal video at all (like you described above), then it makes no sense to leave it enabled.